# How to convert oracle code to java(how to do divide in java)

Tags: java, oracle

I want to convert this [PL/SQL] code to Java code.

```
W_LEDGER_BAL := nvl(SUBSTR(W_BAL, 1, 17), 0) / 100;
```

I have tried to convert like this

```
String amountstr = _ISOResposne.get("48");
String W_LEDGER_BAL = amountstr.substring(0, 17);
```

where `W_BAL` is `amountstr`

I don't know how to divide it by 100.
Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: parse it to a numerical type and divide

Comment: Convert from String to long or BigDecimal, then divide by 100 and finally convert back if the balance really is a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
// Get the value.
String amountstr = _ISOResposne.get("48");

if (amountstr == null) {
    // If it's null, set it to zero.
    amountstr = "0";
}
else {
    // otherwise get the first 17 characters.
    // (Note that if the length is less than 17, an exception will occur.)
    amountstr = amountstr.substring(0, 17);
}
// Convert to a number.
// This will also throw an exception if 'amountstr' cannot be parsed to a number.
java.math.BigDecimal bd = new java.math.BigDecimal(amountstr);

// Divide by one hundred.
bd = bd.divide(new java.math.BigDecimal(100.0d);

// Convert the result to a string.
String W_LEDGER_BAL = bd.toString();
```

Refer to *javadoc* of class [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

I assume you know what an [exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) is in Java.

I also suggest that you try to adhere to [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).